# ~/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are ... at line 3 column 8 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psych

I am a Rails newbie.  Using RoR on Linux mint 16.
Bundle install seems to give me some problems. List of commands that generate this error:
`gem install bundler`, `bundle install --without production`, `bundle update`, `gem install pg`, or any `gem install <insert_gem_here>`  (removed hyperlinks down below)

```
judeman@VB ~/rails_projects/first_app $ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from ://rubygems.org/....
Fetching additional metadata from ://rubygems.org/..
**Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at**
://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 8 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `new'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `configuration'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:48:in `configuration'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:71:in `sources='
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:275:in `remote_specs'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:166:in `fetch_specs'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:216:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:213:in `each'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:213:in `block in index'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:209:in `index'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `resolve'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:82:in `run'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `install'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:334:in `update'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/judeman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

[Bad gemfile]

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

ruby '2.1.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: could you share the gemfile ?

Comment: (working gem file)
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

Comment: i meant `~/rails_projects/first_app/Gemfile`

Comment: (Non working)
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

ruby '2.1.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

Comment: please paste it in the question.

Comment: One last thing.  How to a edit this format so it doesn't look all jacked up and it is easier to read.  (another newbie question).

Comment: paste it in the question :D and check the stackoverflow editor

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I could use Codebunk to make the code easier to read.  Shows someone else's code live.

Comment: no it's common here on stackoverflow to add the code to the question... you can add extra reference if you want to... but don't use it as the main thing :D

Comment: did you run `bundle install` before `bundle update` ? if you didn't then `bundle install`... and there is no need for `bundle update` it updates the gems to the latest version

Comment: Yes I ran bundle install  without production just like this (following along a book i am reading by Michael Hartl RoR). Got an error and tried bundle update next and got the same error:
bundle install --without production

Comment: Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at
http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

Comment: so the `bundle install --without production` is the one failing or `bundle update` ?

Comment: Both, but the problem starts after I add the pg, rails_12factor gems in production and sqlite3 to development.

Comment: I just cloned it to a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 machine ran the same step and it works fine. Bundle install --without production   runs fine.  Rails S runs fine.  I think there is something in my environment I did not set up properly.

Comment: Try uninstalling bundler and install it again `gem uninstall bundler` then start over again

Comment: uninstalling everything.  RVM, ruby, etc

Comment: Try uninstalling bundler and reinstall it first, if the problem still exists then start over remove rvm ruby etc

Comment: When I start gitlab (installed from source) after modify config/gitlab.yml, I got this `Refreshing Gem list
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in 'parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 269 column 5 (Psych::SyntaxError)`. I fixed it follow [Check all yml files for proper syntax](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/736). And I really found that  the indent of the position I modified is 5 spaces which should be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Psych is called probably because in your project you use environment variables or `YAML` files and in one of them there is syntax error.

Check these files:

```
~/.bashrc 
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile

config/dababase.yml
```

If one of them has a syntax error in it, it was capturing the output. I had similiar problem and fixed `~/.profile` error and all is good!